# Parallel locking construct

Tags: c#, locking

I needed an object I can use to serialize specific operations in an otherwise parallel workflow.

The specific use case I was solving for is request idempotency; a great example would be double-clicking a "Process Payment" button on a web form. I might have 100 payment processing requests in flight (parallel process) at any given time, but if two or three come in with the same credit card info, I want to make sure I process them serially (so I can deduplicate, etc.). In that case, a suitable `key` value might be the credit card number.

I came up with the `Keybox` class below. (`Serializer` is **so** overloaded...)

```
public class Keybox : IKeybox
{
    private readonly HashSet<string> Keys = new HashSet<string>();

    public void Lock(string key, int timeout = 60, int tick = 100)
    {
        //timeout is specified in seconds, tick in milliseconds
        //timeout = ConvertTimeoutToTicks(timeout, tick);
        //This logic is not important for the question
        timeout = 600;

        var @event = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        var counter = 0;
        do
        {
            @event.Reset();

            if (!Keys.Contains(key))
            {
                lock (Keys)
                {
                    if (!Keys.Contains(key))
                    {
                        Keys.Add(key);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(tick))
                .ContinueWith(t => @event.Set());

            @event.WaitOne();
        } while (counter++ < timeout);

        throw new Exception($"Unable to process '{key}'; timeout expired.");
    }

    public void Unlock(string key)
    {
        Keys.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
public void Test()
{
    var box = new Keybox();
    var key = "EFF82671-DE8F-46B9-B1F1-0FB8308052C3";

    Parallel.ForEach(
        Enumerable.Range(1, 3),
        (i) =>
        {
            box.Lock(key);
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}: Running");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}: Ending");
            box.Unlock(key);
        }
    );
}
```

which produces output like

```
1: Running
1: Ending
3: Running
3: Ending
2: Running
2: Ending
```

The main question is: is this an implementation of a specific design pattern? And the follow-on to that question is: is there a BCL class that already offers this functionality?

I'm also interested in general code review feedback.

Comment: Does `in flight` here means parallel ?

Comment: @Disappointed `in flight` here means "currently being processed". https://english.stackexchange.com/a/189987/25517

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>     public void Lock(string key, int timeout = 60, int tick = 100)
>     {
>         ...
>         //timeout = ConvertTimeoutToTicks(timeout, tick);
>         ...
>         timeout = 600;
> ```

Looks like you didn't finish tidying up the code.

---

> ```
>         //timeout is specified in seconds, tick in milliseconds
> ```

Why perpetuate the common mistake in the standard libraries? `TimeSpan` exists: use it! I wish Microsoft would `[Obsolete]` every method in .Net which takes an `int` or a `long` for a timespan and replace it with a version taking a `TimeSpan`.

---

> ```
>         var counter = 0;
>         do
>         {
>             ...
>         } while (counter++ < timeout);
> ```

Ok, now I'm even more confused. Is `timeout` supposed to be a timeout or a multiplier of `tick`?

---

> ```
>             if (!Keys.Contains(key))
>             {
>                 lock (Keys)
>                 {
>                     if (!Keys.Contains(key))
>                     {
>                         Keys.Add(key);
>                         return;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
> ```

Just no. .Net's memory model fixes the subtle double-checked locking problem in Java, but only where the test is a simple boolean field. `HashSet` cannot guarantee that multi-threaded access will work correctly if one of the threads modifies it, so the unlocked test must be removed. However, I can offer an improvement which should compensate: use the return value of `Add`:

```
            lock (Keys)
            {
                if (Keys.Add(key))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Similarly, `Unlock` should wrap the current body in a `lock` statement.

---

What's the lifecycle of that `ManualResetEvent`? It's `IDisposable`, so you should take care of tidying it up yourself, probably with a `using` statement.

Comment: +1. Fantastic advice about using `TimeSpan` instead of `int` or `long`. FWIW, the commented lines were indeed tidied up, per this site's admonition to "post working code samples" where possible.

Comment: This is the first time I've worked with `WaitHandle`s, and I thought about checking whether it was `IDisposable` after I put the code up for review, but didn't get back to it.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>         Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(tick))
>             .ContinueWith(t => @event.Set());
>
>         @event.WaitOne();
> ```

I may be missing something, but how is this different from `Thread.Sleep`? And why would you want to pay your worker to sleep? Looks extremely inefficient in most cases.

And surely there are other names you can use apart from `@event`? So you can both avoid using `@` and give a variable a much more meaningful name. "Event" does not tell much.

Comment: There's one important difference between `Thread.Sleep()` and `Task.Delay()` - with `Task.Delay()`, no threads are being blocked while the timeout is awaited. Otherwise, they are behaviorally similar, especially since I'm not using a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: I agree that `@event` is not the greatest name - that's a leftover from the proof-of-concept phase.

Comment: @arootbeer yes, but `event.WaitOne();` is a blocking call so it completely negates any advantages gained by asynchronous nature of `Task.Delay`.

Comment: Heh - the things we take for granted. Looks like I'll be doing some more reading. (Starting here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ComparingTwoTechniquesInNETAsynchronousCoordinationPrimitives.aspx. If you've got suggestions, bring 'em on!)